# How to use rmagic in Azure Notebooks?

Tags: python, r, jupyter

I am trying to get some data out of R snippet to Azure Python 3 Jupyter notebook (hosting is available for free at http://notebooks.azure.com).

I tried the following in Python 3 notebook:

```
%load_ext rmagic
```

then tried to embed R:

```
%%R -o x
x <- 1
```

then

```
x
```

Here I get Python error: `name 'x' is not defined` – see the picture below. What is the right way to embed R into Python 3 and exchange data using Azure Notebooks?

[Azure Notebooks http://nogin.info/R2Py.png](http://nogin.info/R2Py.png)

Comment: The same question has an answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254231/how-to-use-rmagic-in-azure-notebooks/39268025#39268025).